# Pivot row data from a 2d array grouping by one column and summing another column respective to the pivoted column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, pivot

I need to group the data in my 2d array by the `SiteId` column values and then use the `TransactionType` value within that group as the second level key which need to collect the total `Amount` for that transaction in the group.

Input:

```
[
    ['SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Deposit'],
    ['SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Redemption'],
    ['SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '1500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit'],
    ['SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '200.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Reload'],
    ['SiteID' => 150, 'Amount' => '100.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Deposit'],
    ['SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '500.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Redemption'],
    ['SiteID' => 150, 'Amount' => '200.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Redemption'],
    ['SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '500.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Deposit'],
    ['SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '200.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Deposit'],
    ['SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '200.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Reload'],
    ['SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00',  'TransactionType' => 'Redemption']
]
```

Desired Result:

```
[
    147 => ['Deposit' => 2000.0, 'Redemption' => 1000.0, 'Reload' => 200.0],
    150 => ['Deposit' => 100.0, 'Redemption' => 200.0],
    3   => ['Redemption' => 500.0, 'Deposit' => 700.0, 'Reload' => 200.0]
]
```

Comment: How are you getting this data? From MySQL?

Comment: yes form mysql, but the function doesn't require to use a query it should be an array.:)

Comment: Please provide a working array.

Comment: what do you mean by working array? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please provide a working array fragment in future.

```
$transactions = array (
    array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption'),
    array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '1500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 147, 'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Reload' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 150, 'Amount' => '100.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 150, 'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Deposit' ),
    array( 'SiteID' => 3,   'Amount' => '200.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Reload' ),
    array( 'SiteID' =>147, 'Amount' => '500.00', 'TransactionType' => 'Redemption' )
);

$totals = null;

foreach ($transactions as $t){
    $amount = (float) $t['Amount'];
    if (isset($totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ])){
        $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $amount;
    } else {
        $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] = (float) $amount;
    }
}

print_r ($totals);
```

This will produce a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [147] => Array
        (
            [Deposit] => 2000
            [Redemption] => 1000
            [Reload] => 200
        )

    [150] => Array
        (
            [Deposit] => 100
            [Redemption] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Redemption] => 500
            [Deposit] => 700
            [Reload] => 200
        )

)
```

If you can deal with php notice warnings the loop can be shortened to:

```
foreach ($transactions as $t){
    $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $t['Amount'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array destructuring in the `foreach()` to declare convenient variables for later use.

Push associative values into the result array using the id as the first level key, the transaction type as the second level key, and the amount as either the first encountered value or the value to add to a previously encountered element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Wu08E))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['SiteID' => $id, 'Amount' => $amt, 'TransactionType' => $trn]) {
    $result[$id][$trn] = ($result[$id][$trn] ?? 0) + $amt;
}
var_export($result);
```